# How to make script to paste something in with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make a script in AutoHotkey where, when I press Numpad 1, it presses the slash button, then pastes in some text, let's say "hello world", and then presses enter, but I can't figure out how. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
In the future, try to at least show what you tried. All of this should be accomplished pretty easily by e.g. looking at the [beginner tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) combined with a quick Google search.

But well, here it is:

```
Numpad1::
     Clipboard := "/hello word"
     SendInput, ^v{Enter}
return
```

`Numpad1::` creates the hotkey label.
[`Clipboard`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm)`:= ...` puts something into the clipboard.
[`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) sends input.
[`^v`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Parameters) means `Ctrl+v`.
[`{Enter}`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#keynames) means the enter key (could've possibly appended `` `n `` (line feed) into the string as well).
`Return` stops the hotkey label's code execution (in other words, ends the hotkey's code).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have some text copied inside your clipboard before pressing the numpad1, the following code will work.

```
Numpad1::
    Send, /^v    ; ^ means ctrl key,
    Send, {Enter}
return
```